# How did Val and Earl meet and become friends?

Tags: tremors

Is it ever mentioned how Val and Earl met, became friends, and came to live in Perfection?

Comment: My guess is they grew up together in perfection. That kind of place doesn't look like the sort of town you choose to move to unless you're insane and want to be the only guy running a grocery store in a small town.

Comment: Or unless you're a survivalist with food for five years, a thousand gallons of gas, air filtration, water filtration, Geiger counter and a bomb shelter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the film's [screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=tremors), Val and Earl are not originally from Perfection, but almost certain are from the general area, given their knowledge of the people and places around and nearby.

It stands to reason that they met on some job or other and decided that they liked each other enough to go into business, noting that their company sign is simply a hand-painted piece of wood stuck to the side of Earl's truck, so clearly this isn't the most *formal* of arrangements.

**Val's bio describes him thusly;**

> This is VALENTINE MCKEE (25).  Smart and good looking, Val has
> nevertheless managed to underachieve brilliantly.  He coasts through
> life, **following the path of least resistance
> -- which has brought him to this dubious rustic existence on the edge of civilization.**  But lately he's beginning to wonder why he hasn't
> accomplished more in his 25 years.

and Earl's bio has this to say;

> Earl is a good-ol' boy who has **lived his life just like Val, drifting
> from job to job.**  He knows why he hasn't accomplished anything, and
> often tries to impart his hard-won wisdom to Val, but the last thing
> the younger man wants is advice.

Comment: Fantastic answer! After more than three years, I didn't expect to get an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MartinVéronneau - I do sometimes go through the old 'unanswered' stack looking for things that are now answerable. This one jumped out at me because I think I couldn't find the script at the time, but have it now.

Comment: Know that it's greatly appreciated! Thanks again!